Tabularray: 2pt hline and vline border to one row causes other row lines to extend beyond table edge
I am working on my thesis and generated a truth table using tabularray. Everything is fine until I add an hline and vline border around the last row of the table: the hlines for all other rows extend a wee bit beyond the border of the table to the right. Additionally, the color for the first column is also shifted to the right a little.
Def appreciate any assistance/direction. Thanks!

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray,varwidth,enumitem}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Prime Science Truth Table}
\label{tab:my_label}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {*{4}{c}},width = 0.85\linewidth,
    hlines,vlines,
    hline{Y-Z} = {2pt,red},
    vline{1,5} = {9}{2pt,red},
    row{2} = {red9},
    cell{3}{1-2} = {red9},cell{3}{3} = {green9},cell{3}{4} = 
    {red9},
    cell{4}{1} = {red9},cell{4}{2} = {green9},cell{4}{3-4} = 
    {red9},
    cell{5}{1} = {red9},cell{5}{2-3} = {green9},cell{5}{4} = 
    {red9},
    cell{6}{1} = {green9},cell{6}{2-4} = {red9},
    cell{7}{1} = {green9},cell{7}{2} = {red9},cell{7}{3} = 
    {green9},cell{7}{4} = {red9},
    cell{8}{1-2} = {green9},cell{8}{3-4} = {red9},
    row{9} = {green9,font=\bfseries}
    }
    \SetRow{font=\bfseries} Sun Eclipse & Earth Eclipse & Observe 
    Target & Prime Science \\
    F & F & F &  F \\
    F & F & T & F \\
    F & T & F & F \\
    F & T & T & F \\
    T & F & F & F \\
    T & F & T & F \\
    T & T & F & F \\
    T & T & T & T \\
\end{tblr}    
\end{table}


\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE! please make your code snippet be compilable! Then we do not have to guess what yo are doing ...

Sorry about that...first time posting.

It seems to me that this is not supported by tabularray issue #350 and #215 https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/215. It's possible with nicematrix

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Prime Science Truth Table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines]{cccc}
\CodeBefore
    \cellcolor{red9}{2-,3-1,3-2,3-4,4-1,4-3,4-4,5-1,5-4,6-1,6-2,6-3,6-4,7-2,7-4,8-3,8-4}
    \cellcolor{green9}{3-3,4-2,5-2,5-3,6-1,7-1,7-3,8-1,8-2,9-}
\Body
    \RowStyle{\bfseries} 
    Sun Eclipse & Earth Eclipse & Observe 
    Target & Prime Science \\
    F & F & F &  F \\
    F & F & T & F \\
    F & T & F & F \\
    F & T & T & F \\
    T & F & F & F \\
    T & F & T & F \\
    T & T & F & F \\
\Block[draw=red,line-width=2pt,transparent]{1-*}{}
    T & T & T & T \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}



Awesome! Thanks!
